# Extract key data fields from PDFs/Scanned PDFs through machine learning or programmatically for 30 differrent kinds of documents

Tags: python, pdf, machine-learning, text, extract

I have 30 different types of PDFs. I need to extract information specific to each PDF. I need to do it in python preferably. I am able to extract specific information from one type of pdf but need a model which will recognize the type of document and automatically identify the keywords which need to be extracted and then retrieve them. Is it possible programmatically using python? Any help will be appreciated. 
Please note that not all the documents are structured. But for the start we can assume that the document is structured.

I have tried OpenCV for text extraction from scanned images but it is giving me horrible results. I have converted the whole images to text but that's not what I am looking for. I am just looking for specific information from each of the pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things.

For the Keywords, you can use [tf-idf](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/tf-idf-statistic-keyword-extraction/)
For the Topic extraction you can use [document classification](https://github.com/richliao/textClassifier)

Comment: I have tried that, but that's not the case. Suppose for a W9 form I need Tax Number and Name to be extracted. But for say some other form, I need to extract some other information.  I just want specific information to be extracted. Also I have already classified the document.

Comment: Hard to help you with this without examples of the input